# Cohomology of doubly pinched torus via spectral sequences

Tags: sheaf-theory, singularity, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Let $f:T^2\to Y$ be a resolution of singularities where $Y$ is a torus with two "pinched" points (or, if you prefer, two copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ meeting at two points).  I'm interested in using the Leray spectral sequence to calculate the cohomology of the constant sheaf on $Y$ . My goal is to better understand spectral sequences and this looks like a nice example to me.

To begin with, $Rf_*\mathbb{Q}_X$ has cohomology sheaves $R^0f_*\mathbb{Q}_X = \mathbb{Q}_Y$ and $R^1f_*\mathbb{Q}_X = \mathcal{S}_{\{a,b\}}$, the skyscraper sheaf with stalk $\mathbb{Q}$ at the pinched points $a,b$.

The $E_2$ page is
\begin{align*}
\begin{matrix}
H^2(Y; \mathbb{Q}_Y) & 0 & 0\\
H^1(Y; \mathbb{Q}_Y) & 0& 0\\
H^0(Y; \mathbb{Q}_Y) & H^0(Y;\mathcal{S}_{\{a,b\}})=\mathbb{Q}^{\oplus 2}  & 0
\end{matrix} 
\end{align*}
and the $E_3 (=E_\infty)$ page is
\begin{align*}
\begin{matrix}
H^2(Y; \mathbb{Q}_Y)/ \text{im}(d_2^{0,1}) & 0 &0 \\
H^1(Y; \mathbb{Q}_Y) & 0& 0\\
H^0(Y; \mathbb{Q}_Y) & \text{ker}(d_2^{0,1})  & 0
\end{matrix} 
\end{align*}

Using the fact that $H^n(T^2)$ is filtered by these objects, we have $H^0(T^2) = E_\infty^{0,0} = E_2^{0,0} = H^0(Y)$ which obviously makes sense,
as well as filtrations $$E_3^{0,1}\hookrightarrow H^1(X)$$ where $H^1(X) / \text{ker}(d^{0,1}_2) = E^{1,0}_3 = H^1(Y)$ and $$E_3^{0,2}\hookrightarrow (?) \hookrightarrow H^2(X)$$ where $H^2(X) / (?) = E^{2,0}_3 = H^2(Y)/\text{im}(d^{0,1}_2)$ and $(?)/E^{0,2}_3 = E^{1,1}_3$.  Since $E^{1,1}_3 = 0 = E^{0,2}_3$, this implies $H^2(Y)/\text{im}(d^{0,1}_2) = H^2(X)$.

How can I get my hands on the differential $d_2^{0,1}$ in order to finish this calculation?

Comment: I believe the filtration of $H^1(X)$ goes the other way around : $H^1(Y)\subset H^1(X)$ and the quotient is $H^1(X)/H^1(Y)=\ker(d_2^{0,1})$. Now you need to understand this $\ker(d_2^{0,1})=\operatorname{im}(H^1(X)\to H^0(Y,\mathcal{S}_{a,b}))$. For this, you can work locally. You will find in particular that it is of the image is of dimension 1 and this will gives all the dimensions of $H^i(Y)$. Let me know if you can work this out or if you want me to write a full answer (which might not come immediately).

Comment: Right, I'm using the wrong orientation I think.  Anyways, using the map to $H^0$ is exactly what I needed, thanks!